# Dealing with NAN Values in Xarray when using .sum() for a basin NetCDF file

Tags: python, numpy, nan, python-xarray, shapefile

The following code takes a global precipitation NetCDF file with daily data and a basin shape file as input data. The precipitation data is clipped as it would be done in ArcGIS or QGIS using the basin shape file. So far so good.

I have an issue, however, in the last line: `sum_data =  clipped_nc.resample({"time": "month"}).sum(keep_attrs=True, skipna=True)`. Here, I want to get the monthly precipitation sum.

The problem is that everything outside the basin before the sum is NaN values, but as soon as I calculate `sum_data` the NaN values become ZEROS.

I know that in that last line I have `skipna=True`. I decided to keep it as true because sometimes I encountered missing precipitation data (NaN) inside the basin and when I was summing real measured data with missing data I was getting NaN as a result. So I solved that issue by doing `skipna=True`, turns out now I have the issue I just mentioned with the values outside the basin as ZEROS instead of NaN.

**This is the code:**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import mapping

# Load shapefile
shapefile_path = "my_shapefile.shp"
shapefile = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path, crs="epsg:4326")

# Load NetCDF file
netcdf_path = "my_netcdffile.nc"
ds = xr.open_dataset(netcdf_path)

pre = ds["pre"] # selecting precipitation

# clipping
pre.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
pre.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
basin = pre.rio.clip(
    shapefile.geometry.apply(mapping), pre.rio.crs
)

sum_data =  basin.resample({"time": "month"}).sum(keep_attrs=True, skipna=True)
```

I have attached two pictures

NetCDF file before `sum_data` where all values outside basin are -9999:

[image: NetCDF file before sum_data]

And NetCDF file after `sum_data` where all values outside basin become 0:

[image]

As you can see the NaN values outside the basin are messed up for `sum_data`. I do not know how to keep NaN values outside the basin as NaN, while ignoring possible NaN values inside the basin for calculation such as sum, mean, variance and so on.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: During `sum` aggregation, `NaN` values are treated as zeros, resulting in all fully `NaN` pixels to remain `0`. To deal with this, I'd suggest to create a no-data mask beforehand, and then use it afterwards to set those `NaN` pixels to a nodata value (or back to `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it taking the recommendation made by @val.

Here is the last section of the code posted before with two new lines that fixed my issue:

```
basin = pre.rio.clip(
    shapefile.geometry.apply(mapping), pre.rio.crs
)

basin_mask = ~np.isnan(basin)

sum_data =  basin.resample({"time": "month"}).sum(keep_attrs=True)    

sum_data = sum_data.where(basin_mask)
```